# Automation Anywhere fails with "destination mailbox was not found or could not be accessed"

Tags: automationanywhere

I use send mail on automation anywhere but program error massage,

"The destination mailbox was not found or could not be accessed."

please Knowledgeable person help advice me.
thank you.

Comment: Did you used the correct destination email address?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a community edition then the send email command won't work most probably. But if you are using Enterprise editions then check the following:

1. Check if the all mails given are correct.
2. In AA client goto Tools->Options->Email settings and check the correct host and port number.

If the above methods don't work that means the SMTP settings of the your system are not done or your system doesn't have enough authorization. Either you may have to raise some request in your organization to open that particular port for you or something similar to get it fixed.

Comment: My host and port number, can send  email internal company (exam: name.lastname@mycompany_name.com) but can not send to external email all (exam: mail_name@gmail.com, or hotmail.com etc.)

Comment: Try changing the firewall settings maybe that's stopping AA from sending or else the platform team might have to change some settings to allow external programs to send Emails from their network to outside of their network.